# Узнать разницу между временем пользователя и сервера Python

Tags: python, datetime

Мне нужно создать приложение, которое будет во время, указанное пользователем, делать то или иное действие.
Предположим, что пользователь захотел, что бы в 12:05 выполнялось действие. Все бы ничего, но у сервера и клиента время совсем разное: у сервера может быть 5:00, а у пользователя - 9:00.

Я сделал так, что бы при первом запуске пользователь вводил его текущее время, (в формате [часы]:[минуты], 10:05 к примеру) однако сделать систему "разницы" между временами сервера и пользователя не смог. Не могли бы вы подсказать, как можно сохранить разницу во времени, что бы каждый раз можно было её извлекать, и далее добавлять к времени сервера полученное значение?

Работать с datatime я вообще не умею :)

Comment: https://howchoo.com/g/ywi5m2vkodk/working-with-datetime-objects-and-timezones-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now()
b = datetime.datetime.now()
c = b - a
```

Попробуйте это в интерпретаторе и далее сами поймете что делать с результатом и во что преобразовывать :)